# What is the expected variance from the mean as the sample size increases?

Tags: probability, statistics

If I roll a 6-sided dice $n$ times, the average dice roll should converge to the "true" mean 3.5 as $n$ gets very large.

My question is: what is the expected variance from the mean given $n$ dice rolls? (And my ultimate goal: how many rolls do I need to do in order to have an expected variance of <0.01 from 3.5?)

Comment: Are you looking for $\mathsf{Var}(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nD_i)$ (with iif $D_i$ uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$)? That is elementary.

Comment: @drhab Yes, I think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: If rv's are independent then the variance of a sum is the sum of variances. Next to that we have $\mathsf{Var}(aX)=a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$ if $a$ is a constant. This is enough.

Comment: So you can find the variance of a single dice roll.  The variance of the mean of $n$ dice rolls is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and the standard error of the mean is the square root of that

Comment: @Henry Ah, that's what I was looking for (Standard Error)! How do you find the variance of a single die roll?

Comment: $Var(D)=E[(D-E[D])^2] = \sum\limits_{d=1}^6 \frac16 (d-3.5)^2$